# Why does Box<[T]> need 16 bytes in memory, but a referenced slice needs only 8? (on x64 machine)

Tags: rust

Consider:

```rust
fn main() {
    // Prints 8, 8, 16
    println!(
        "{}, {}, {}",
        std::mem::size_of::<Box<i8>>(),
        std::mem::size_of::<Box<&[i8]>>(),
        std::mem::size_of::<Box<[i8]>>(),
    );
}
```

Why do owned slices take 16 bytes, but referenced slices take only 8?

Comment: Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a42b29f4e0bbb411ee2c6db66120fee4

Comment: Previous discussion: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt6L3.png

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Box<T>` is basically `*const T` (Actually it's a newtype around `Unique<T>`, which itself is a `NonNull<T>` with `PhantomData<T>` (for [dropck](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/dropck.html)), but let's stick to `*const T` for simplicity).

A pointer in Rust normally has the same size as `size_of::<usize>()` except when `T` is a [dynamically sized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/dynamically-sized-types.html) (DST). Currently, a `Box<DST>` is `2 * size_of::<usize>()` in size (the exact representation is not stable at the time of writing). A pointer to a DST is called `FatPtr`.

Currently, there are two kinds of DSTs: Slices and traits. A `FatPtr` to a slice is defined like this:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct FatPtr<T> {
    data: *const T,
    len: usize,
}
```

*Note:* For a trait pointer, `len` is replaced by a pointer to the `vtable`.

With this information, your question can be answered:

- `Box<i8>`: `i8` is a sized type => basically the same as `*const i8` => 8 bytes in size (with 64-bit pointer width)
- `Box<[i8]>`: `[i8]` is a DST => basically the same as `FatPtr<i8>` => 16 bytes in size (with 64-bit pointer width)
- `Box<&[i8]>`: `&[i8]` is **not** a DST. It's basically the same as `*const FatPtr<i8>` => 8 bytes in size (with 64-bit pointer width)

Answer (score 8):

The size of a reference depends on the "sizedness" of the referenced type:

- A reference to a sized type is a single pointer to the memory address.
- A reference to an unsized type is a pointer to the memory **and** the size of the pointed datum. That's what is called a [fat pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.34.0/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#54):

  ```rust
  #[repr(C)]
  struct FatPtr<T> {
      data: *const T,
      len: usize,
  }
  ```

A `Box` is a special kind of pointer that points to the heap, but it is still a pointer.

Knowing that, you understand that:

- `Box<i8>` is 8 bytes because `i8` is sized,
- `Box<&[i8]>` is 8 bytes because a reference is sized,
- `Box<[i8]>` is 16 bytes because a slice is unsized.